# rasterio plot and QGIS display different colours

Tags: qgis, rasterio

I created a script to separate individual bands from two multiband .tif files in order to combine them in a "custom" multiband .tif. I also clip them into 3 smaller study areas. When

I display them in QGIS and rasterio and they are completely different. In QGIS, all dark colours are gone.  I think this is because I missed the alpha band. Nevertheless, the all other raster values are like the originals.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a stretch is applied to the raster in the QGIS.

Reset these settings or adjust them:

[image]

Comment: I tried this settings for Singleband as in your image and for the multiband (My max values are 255 , and min, 0 or 2) . I still have the same issue. Just to give an example, the shades of buildings are bright